# Adding a button to MediaController

Tags: mediacontroller

I want to add a button to MediaController. So I extended MediaController class, created a button and added it into the frame layout. But the newly added button is not reflecting while running.

Please find the code below

```
 public class VideoController extends MediaController {

private Button searchButton;
public VideoController(Context context) {
    super(context);

    searchButton = new Button(context);
    searchButton.setText("Search");
    FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
    System.out.println("Adding a button");

    addView(searchButton, params);
    //updateViewLayout(this, params);
}

@Override
public void hide() {
}
}
```

what I am doing wrong here. Any suggestions will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How have you added button in mediaController? can you share your code or some tips thanks

Answer (score 14):

You have to override `setAnchorView` in your `VideoController` class:

```
 @Override 
 public void setAnchorView(View view) {
     super.setAnchorView(view);

     Button searchButton = new Button(context);
     searchButton.setText("Search");
     FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
     params.gravity = Gravity.RIGHT;
     addView(searchButton, params);
}
```

Comment: What does setanchorview do

Answer (score 1):

Actually that happens because media controller's view is constructed later (in **makeControllerView** method). So you need to override it and add button there.

Unfortunately, it is hidden at the moment. And overriding setAnchorView seems the best solution.